# Shell Script - how to scp into remote server and download files and protect password

Tags: ssh, scripting, security, scp, authorization

I have a remote server that I need to download Apache logs from.

I can manually `scp` into the server and get the files, but I'd like to put this in crontab. The only way to automate it is to include the password of the target server which I'd rather not do.

What would you recommend to `scp` into the other server, get files and download them to another machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a private/public key pair on the client machine, and copying the public key to the remote machine.

You can generate such a keypair with `ssh-keygen` and copy it to the remote machine using `ssh-copy-id`.

The logs are probably readable by all user accounts on the server (at least they are on my machine). You should therefore not use the `root` account on the server for this, as root access to your client would mean root access to the remote machine.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, that's the best strategy. I'll do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can authorize as many public keys as you like on the server side. Furthermore, you can restrict a key to a specific command on the server side. So generate an SSH key pair on the client, and don't put a password on the private key. Append the public key to the list of authorized keys, and add a command restriction.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/apache-logs-download.id_rsa -N ''
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/apache-logs-download.id_rsa server.example.com:
```

On the server, edit the newly added line of [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) (`ssh-copy-id` tacks it on at the end) and add the forced command directive:

```
command="/usr/bin/rrsync -ro /var/log/apache",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA…
```

[`rrsync`](http://ftp.samba.org/pub/unpacked/rsync/support/rrsync) is a wrapper script around rsync that is specifically designed to allow rsync over SSH only to or from a specific directory. Change the path above if `rrsync` is in a directory other than `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Gilles, I've created the pair and uploaded apache-logs-download.id_rsa as listed above, but when I log in I still get prompted for a password. What should I check?

Comment: Never mind, my mistake. /etc/ssh/ssh_config wasn't set to use keys. My bad.