# SCP Automation in production environment

Tags: shell-script, scripting, scp

I want to implement the use of `scp` command in a production environment. I don't want to provide my password in the automation script.

Is there any way?

I need step by step solution.

Comment: You should look into using public keys. Look at `man ssh-keygen` to begin with.

Comment: ...or use `expect`. But public keys are much better

Answer (score 1):

Following an article from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/):

> *You should [setup SSH connection without Password Using ssh-keygen](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) then it will allow you to use scp without prompting
> password or any other remote task:*

**3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id**

You can login to a remote Linux server without entering password in 3 simple steps using `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` as explained in [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/).

- `ssh-keygen` creates the public and private keys.
- `ssh-copy-id` copies the local-host’s public key to the remote-host’s
  authorized_keys file. It also assigns proper permission to
  the remote-host’s home, `~/.ssh`, and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

This article also explains 3 minor annoyances of using `ssh-copy-id` and how to use `ssh-copy-id` along with `ssh-agent`.

---

#### Step 1: Create public and private keys using ssh-key-gen on local-host

```
jsmith@local-host$ [Note: You are on local-host here]
jsmith@local-host$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa):[Enter key]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Press enter key]
Enter same passphrase again: [Pess enter key]
Your identification has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
33:b3:fe:af:95:95:18:11:31:d5:de:96:2f:f2:35:f9 jsmith@local-host
```

**Step 2: Copy the public key to remote-host using ssh-copy-id**

```
jsmith@local-host$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
jsmith@remote-host's password:
```

**Note:** `ssh-copy-id` appends the keys to the remote-host’s `.ssh/authorized_key`.

**Step 3: Login to remote-host without entering the password**

```
jsmith@local-host$ ssh remote-host
Last login: Sun Nov 16 17:22:33 2008 from 192.168.1.2
[Note: SSH did not ask for password.]

 jsmith@remote-host$ [Note: You are on remote-host here]
```

---

The above 3 simple steps should get the job done in most cases.

We also discussed earlier in detail about performing SSH and SCP from openSSH to openSSH without entering password.

If you are using SSH2, we discussed earlier about performing SSH and SCP without password from SSH2 to SSH2, from OpenSSH to SSH2 and from SSH2 to OpenSSH.

#### Using `ssh-copy-id` along with the `ssh-add`/`ssh-agent`.

When no value is passed for the option `-i` and if `~/.ssh/identity.pub` is not available, `ssh-copy-id` will display the following error message:

```
 jsmith@local-host$ ssh-copy-id -i remote-host
 /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
```

If you have loaded keys to the `ssh-agent` using the `ssh-add`, then `ssh-copy-id` will get the keys from the `ssh-agent` to copy to the remote-host. i.e, it copies the keys provided by `ssh-add -L` command to the remote-host, when you don’t pass option `-i` to the `ssh-copy-id`.

```
 jsmith@local-host$ ssh-agent $SHELL

 jsmith@local-host$ ssh-add -L
 The agent has no identities.

 jsmith@local-host$ ssh-add
 Identity added: /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa)

 jsmith@local-host$ ssh-add -L
 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsJIEILxftj8aSxMa3d8t6JvM79DyBV
 aHrtPhTYpq7kIEMUNzApnyxsHpH1tQ/Ow== /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa

 jsmith@local-host$ ssh-copy-id -i remote-host
 jsmith@remote-host's password:
```

Now try logging into the machine, with `ssh 'remote-host'`, and check in: `.ssh/authorized_keys` to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

**Note:** This has added the key displayed by `ssh-add -L`.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. i was trying to create  a generic user and give it sudo access and use it in scp automation script. I want a secure way to do this. i am not very sure how public key works.will try tht. wats the difference between scp and ssh..which one is more sceure?

Comment: `SSH` is secure shell and `SCP` is command allow you to copy file over ssh connection

Comment: Hi Raza, I am trying the method you suggested. on the 2nd step,i am getting error as "/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found", if i am not on sudo. i logged in to sudo n tried again. and now getting error as "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password)."

Comment: Hi Raza, i copied the files to destination. now i can login to destination(ssh remotehost) from source without entering password. but if i do scp, its asking for password.

Comment: check the permission of ./ssh directory and authorized_keys. make sure you have copy the key correctly. You can always check error message under /var/log/secure to see what exactly going wrong.

Comment: Hi Raza, I followed ur steps. its working fine if i am doing scp user@sourceserver:folder/file at target server .But if i am doing   "scp user@sourceserver:folder/file user@sourceserver:folder/file" at source, Its asking me password for source.PLs suggest

Comment: if you are remote ssh into sourceserver and then trying to do  scp `user@sourceserver:folder/file user@sourceserver:folder/file` then you need to make sure that agent forwarding is enabled. if you are using putty then you can find this option under Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> “Allow agent forwarding”.

Comment: Hi Raza, i did as u said. now i am using the statement scp user@sourceserver:path/filename user@targetserver:path/filename at SOURCE server.its still asking me for source password and throwing error publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password.

user@source's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
lost connection
PSWD
Connection to target closed.

Comment: sorry to hear that you are still having this issue. You could enable debug print to get more detail error logs to make sense out of it... normally, this process it simple as describe in steps above

Comment: Hi Raza, i want to write a scp command in server1 to copy data from server2 and paste it to server3.

Comment: assuming you are on server1 then `scp file user@server2:/file && ssh server2 "scp path/file user@server3:file"`

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- use `ssh-keygen` procedure as suggested in comment and answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141296/shell-script-how-to-scp-into-remote-server-and-download-files-and-protect-pass). For a longer version you can use even [this link Linux Cookbook](https://www.gotraveltech.com/confluence/display/COOK/Linux).

  It can open a security hole if you use shared account on your machine (**everybody from that account can access to all the machine for which you did the ssh-keygen authentication**).
- write a little script that asks for password and passes it to the command lines with `scp` command.  e.g in `MyScript.sh`

  ```
  #/bin/bash  
  sshpass -p $1 scp file.tar.gz user@destination_url:destination_path  
  sshpass -p $1 scp file2.rar user2@other_destination_url:destination_path    
  # ....
  ```

You can execute it with `/bin/bash MyScript.sh yourpassword` or (if before you change the attributes with `chmod u+x MyScript.sh`) with `./MyScript.sh yourpassword`.
If you add a **blank space before the command** and the shell is set correctly this command will not finish in the history and neither your password.
You can check it with `echo $HISTCONTROL`. If it contains the value `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth` the history will not remember any command that starts with an empty space. If not you can add `export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`
in your file `~/.bashrc`.

**Note:** With `$1` inside a script, you refer to the first parameter with which you call the script.